# Vue nested dynamic routes without route prefix

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have set up a locale parameter, for example: `/en`.

My goal is to achieve a nested category lookup by routes for example:

1. with placeholders: `/:locale/:category/:subcategory/:process`
2. real world example: `/en/business/tax/1c7e7b66-ec6c-4431-9e84-87f2f2ace369`

The issue is when I attempt to access the subcategory route the router displays the category component.

Please see my router file below:

router/main.js

```
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:locale',
      props: true,
      component: {
        render (c) { return c('router-view') }
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: ':categorySlug/',
          name: 'category',
          component: Category,
          props: true,
          children: [
            {
              path: ':subcategorySlug',
              name: 'subcategory',
              component: Subcategory,
              props: true,
              children: [
                {
                  path: ':processId',
                  name: 'process',
                  component: Process,
                  props: true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the `/` in the child path like this and not in the parent path :

```
children: [
        {
          path: '/:categorySlug',
          name: 'category',
          component: Category,
          props: true,
          children: [
            {
              path: '/:subcategorySlug',
              name: 'subcategory',
              component: Subcategory,
              props: true,
              children: [
                {
                  path: '/:processId',
                  name: 'process',
                  component: Process,
                  props: true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: This doesn't load the category component, it doesn't load any component.

Comment: Yeah sry, i forgot the `/` for the first node. Now it must be wowrking

Comment: Unfortunately not, (now it's not loading any components on any route, apart from `/en` and it's loading the subcategory component.